# QFile myFile.copy(newFile) failed, but myFile.error returns 0 (this means NoError)

Tags: qt, copy, qfile

I am using Qt 4.6.3 with SUSE 11 Linux and I try to copy a file with QFile:

```
QFile myFile ("/my/path/myFile.txt");

if (!myFile.copy("/my/otherpath/myNewFile.txt")){
    cout << "Qt error: " << myFile.error() << endl;
}
```

If there is enough place on the device, everything is ok.

In case of disk is full and if I try to copy the file in a linux console with bash, then I got an error message.

```
cp /my/path/myFile.txt /my/path/myFile.txt
cp: writing `/my/path/myFile.txt': No space left on device
```

In my C++ program myFile.copy() returns "false", but myFile.error() returns '0'.
I expected that myFile.error() returns a value not '0.

Furthermore I tried myFile.errorString() and have got "Unknown error" as the result.

Is it possible to get an errorcode or message like "No space left on device" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the target file already exists. Documentation http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qfile.html#copy says:

> If a file with the name `newName` already exists, `copy()` returns false.

This is not an actual error condition, because it is normal for `copy()` not to overwrite. Check for its existence. And when you are inspecting for file error, do it with the error enum, eg:

```
QFile from("fromFile");
QFile target("targetFile");
if (target.exists())
    target.remove();
if (target.error() != QFile::NoError)
    // remove error
from.copy(target.fileName());
if (from.error() != QFile::NoError)
    // copy error
```

Comment: Thx! Yes, the the target file already exits. That was my fault.